# Spring Boot fails to load resources from subdirectories

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to save different css and js files in different subdirectories and this is my directory structure

[image: structure]

Then I tried import all these files into my index.html file (which is mapped by "/") but none of them were imported properly. What should I configure to enable Spring boot to search for resources recursively in all subdirectories under "resources"? Also what should I do if I also want to put all html templates in subdirectories?

[image: errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `../static/` as spring boot automatically expose all directories and sub-directories in the static folder on your main endpoint (default `/`).

so for example use:

`<script src="js/jquery-1.11.8.min.js" ... />`